# Module 'Firebase' has no member named 'configure'

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm doing a job as an internee in a software house in iOS Swift language using Xcode.

I have an issue in creating a Firebase database. I got an error on creating a database for my realtime project. When I write `Firebase.configure()`, I got the error:

> "Module 'Firebase' has no member named 'configure'".

Kindly help me to get rid of this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Firebase.configure()` you should be using `FirebaseApp.configure()`.

Source: [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize-firebase)